# Pairwise and Mutually disjoint sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between Pairwise and Mutually disjoint sets? The context of this is measure theory.

Comment: No difference: both mean that if $A$ and $B$ are distinct sets in the family in question, then $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the meaning of pairwise disjoint and mutually disjoint sets. If two sets are pairwise disjoint, it can be also said they are mutually disjoint as well.